# how count downloads of a file with jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

Anyone knows some jquery plugin to count how many times a file (pdf, in my case) is download from your server??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use the google analytics javascript API with an onclick event

Then you can have beautiful charts for your downloads. see here for an example case : http://think2loud.com/use-jquery-with-google-analytics-to-track-clicks-on-outgoing-links-from-your-site/

Answer (score 1):

You can create script download.php that count your download links.

```
<?php

// connect to database
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    $file = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['file']);
    $query = "insert into downloads VALUES('$file', 1) on duplicate key " . 
      "update count = count + 1;, count+1)";
    mysql_query($query);
}
?>
```

downloads table is:

```
create table downloads(file VARCHAR(255) primary key, count integer default 1)
```

and in jQuery

```
$('a.download').click(function() {
   //empty function don't care what I get.
   $.get('download.php', {file: $(this).attr('href')}, function() {});
});
```

it call download.php script with href attribute on every link that have download class

**UPDATE**  I forget to add return false because in code above it call ajax and then abort it.

```
$('a.download').click(function() {
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
   $.get('download.php', {file: link}, function() {
       // change url to link when ajax is finished
       window.location = link;
   });
   // prevent following the link
   return false;
});
```

You can also add code that prevent multiply clicks because there will be delay between ajax call finish and changing url to link of a element (user may click few times because it will not folow the link) and you can add CTRL+click because it open link in other window (you can return true in this case).

Comment: Can you elaborate little more. How the jQuery code is linked to the download file link ?

Comment: You send href of the link via ajax to download.php script via file query parameter. If user click a.download link it execute download.php script, I forget to add return false and change location in response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to determine how many times a single user clicks on a given link on a given fully-rendered page, and use that value to update a database table of download clicks through AJAX, but jQuery doesn't have any direct insight into your server-side data as relates to the total number of downloads, you would have to be updating a database with that data and displaying it from there. you could use jQuery to watch and see if that value changes (on a timer maybe) and update your page accordingly, butthat still requires a AJAX call to a database lookup.

jQuery is a library for Javascript with is a client-side language and acts on the page once it is downloaded and running on the client's machine and as such is not the place for server-side logic and lookups except in the cases where AJAX is warranted and needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.  jQuery code runs in a user's browser, not on a server.  To count downloads you'll need server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery alone won't be able to do that.

You would have to keep track on the server each time the file is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway to modify the above script to allow only 1 download per user in a set period of time based on the date they joined the site, i.e. the user can only download the file once per year starting from the day they joined the site?

I'm using Wordpress to run my site.

Thanks